# CSS :hover not working the way I expect

Tags: hover, foreground

I have a div which belongs to the class .stickyNote and within that div I have a `<h1>` tag as the title of the stickyNote and a `<p>` tag as the contents of the stickynote. Just like so: `<div class="stickyNote">
                <h1>Drag Me</h1>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum..</p>
            </div>-->`

The stickyNote class is styled so that when one hovers over it, it will come a little more to the foreground, with this CSS:

```
.stickyNote :hover,.stickyNote :focus{  
   -moz-box-shadow:10px 10px 7px rgba(0,0,0,.7);  
   -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 7px rgba(0,0,0,.7);  
   box-shadow:10px 10px 7px rgba(0,0,0,.7);  
   -webkit-transform: scale(1.25);  
   -moz-transform: scale(1.25);  
   -o-transform: scale(1.25);  
   position:relative;  
   z-index:5;  
 }
```

However, when I hover over the stickyNote div the `<h1>` and the `<p>` section always come to the foreground seperately, i.e. when I hover over the `<h1>` it will come to the foreground and when I hover over the `<p>` it will come to the foreground, but never the whole stickyNote.
What am I missing?
div as a whole.

Comment: You have a space between `.stickyNote` and `:hover` so your CSS is saying apply this style to children of `.stickyNote` that are hovered.

Comment: That is to stay. Get rid of the space, noob.

Comment: a noob I truly am. but i don't have any children that are hovered??? (your solution still works though)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
.stickyNote :hover, .stickyNote :focus{
```

not comma first

```
.stickyNote :hover .stickyNote :focus{
```

Comment: that one doesn't really seem to make any difference